# Vaadin Upload Component Upload Button, changing it's Style?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

How to apply `setStyleName("small")` on an Upload component’s upload button and have it work?  If this requires custom CSS it would be great to see an example of what that looks like.  This question is for the Upload Button, not the "browse" button, which has been hidden by `setImmediate(true)` in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this scss for the small upload buttons:

```
.v-upload-small .v-button
{
    height: 31px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

And on the upload button use the `addStyleName("small")` instead of `setStyleName(...)`