# Vaadin Upload Button, CSS to change its color (same styles as Button)?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

What would be the **CSS** that would allow me to change the upload button's color to one of the following: **danger**, **primary** or **friendly** so that I may use `setStyleName()` in the same way as I do for a Button ?

Ref:
https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-button.html

This Doc doesn't discuss the bug or fix:
https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-upload.html

But does say:

> The upload button has the same structure and style as a regular Button component.

So, I guess that the SCSS or CSS that isn't included for this "button" is either an omission, oversight, or bug.

Comment: Similar as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835618/vaadin-upload-component-upload-button-changing-its-style

Comment: @AndréSchild I've revised the question.

Comment: @AndréSchild -- running into problem here too, maybe you know?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959442/vaadin-how-to-limit-component-squishiness-and-overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by finding "danger", "primary" and "friendly" in the source and simply copying them out, pasting them into `mytheme.scss` then changing the style names as **@AndreSchild** describes in the following answer:

[Vaadin Upload Component Upload Button, changing it's Style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835618/vaadin-upload-component-upload-button-changing-its-style)

Here's the updated CSS (paste into `mytheme.scss`) and use `setStyleName` as you would for a regular button component:

```
    .v-upload-primary .v-button {
            height: 37px;
            padding: 0 16px;
            color: #ecf2f8;
            font-weight: 400;       
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #1362b1;
            border-top-color: #156ab3;
            border-bottom-color: #1156a8;
            background-color: #197de1;
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1b87e3 2%, #166ed5 98%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#1b87e3 2%, #166ed5 98%);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #4d98e6, inset 0 -1px 0 #166bca, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #4d98e6, inset 0 -1px 0 #166bca, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            padding: 0 19px;
            font-weight: bold;
            min-width: 81px;
     }

    .v-upload-primary .v-button:after {
            border: inherit;
            top: -1px;
            right: -1px;
            bottom: -1px;
            left: -1px;
    }

    .v-upload-primary .v-button:hover:after {
            background-color: rgba(90, 163, 237, 0.1);
    }

    .v-upload-primary .v-button:focus:after {
            border: inherit;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(25, 125, 225, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(25, 125, 225, 0.5);
    }

    .v-upload-primary .v-button:active:after {
            background-color: rgba(2, 62, 122, 0.2);
    }

    .v-ie8 .v-upload-primary .v-button {
            min-width: 43px;
    }

    .v-upload-friendly .v-button  {
            height: 37px;
            padding: 0 16px;
            color: #eaf4e9;
            font-weight: 400;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #227719;
            border-top-color: #257d1a;
            border-bottom-color: #1e6b15;
            background-color: #2c9720;
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f9f22 2%, #26881b 98%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#2f9f22 2%, #26881b 98%);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #46b33a, inset 0 -1px 0 #26811b, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #46b33a, inset 0 -1px 0 #26811b, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }

    .v-upload-friendly .v-button:after {
            border: inherit;
            top: -1px;
            right: -1px;
            bottom: -1px;
            left: -1px;
    }

    .v-upload-friendly .v-button:hover:after {
            background-color: rgba(65, 211, 48, 0.1);
    }

    .v-upload-friendly .v-button:focus:after {
            border: inherit;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(25, 125, 225, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(25, 125, 225, 0.5);
    }

    .v-upload-friendly .v-button:active:after {
            background-color: rgba(14, 86, 6, 0.2);
    }

    .v-upload-danger .v-button {
            height: 37px;
            padding: 0 16px;
            color: #f9f0ef;
            font-weight: 400;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #bb382e;
            border-top-color: #bc3c31;
            border-bottom-color: #b13028;
            background-color: #ed473b;
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ee4c3f 2%, #e13e33 98%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#ee4c3f 2%, #e13e33 98%);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ef786f, inset 0 -1px 0 #da3c31, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ef786f, inset 0 -1px 0 #da3c31, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }

    .v-upload-danger .v-button:after {
            border: inherit;
            top: -1px;
            right: -1px;
            bottom: -1px;
            left: -1px;
    }

    .v-upload-danger .v-button:hover:after {
            background-color: rgba(243, 137, 129, 0.1);
    }

    .v-upload-danger .v-button:focus:after {
            border: inherit;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(25, 125, 225, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(25, 125, 225, 0.5);
    }

    .v-upload-danger .v-button:active:after {
            background-color: rgba(146, 12, 2, 0.2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to hide the upload button inside the component by using css. And then add a standard Vaadin button in your code next to the Upload component. Just call `upload.submit()` inside the click listener of your button.

Now it's easy to apply those standard style names to that button.