# Vaadin 8: Customize button color

Tags: vaadin8

I want to change the green color from the valo "friendly" button but I failed.
I did as described in 
[Vaadin Upload Button, CSS to change its color (same styles as Button)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965542/vaadin-upload-button-css-to-change-its-color-same-styles-as-button)
but I think I missed something.

From the styles.css I copied the

```
.mytheme .v-button-friendly {
height: 37px;
padding: 0 16px;
color: #eaf4e9;
font-weight: 400;


border-radius: 4px;
border: 1px solid #227719;
border-top-color: #257d1a;
border-bottom-color: #1e6b15;
background-color: #2c9720;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f9f22 2%, #26881b 98%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#2f9f22 2%, #26881b 98%);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #46b33a, inset 0 -1px 0 #26811b, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #46b33a, inset 0 -1px 0 #26811b, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

to the mytheme.scss and just changed the color.
mytheme.scss looks now as follows:

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {
   @include valo;

.v-button-sgcgreen {
height: 37px;
padding: 0 16px;
color: #006666;
font-weight: 400;


border-radius: 4px;
border: 1px solid #227719;
border-top-color: #257d1a;
border-bottom-color: #1e6b15;
background-color: #006666;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f9f22 2%, #26881b 98%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#2f9f22 2%, #26881b 98%);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #46b33a, inset 0 -1px 0 #26811b, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #46b33a, inset 0 -1px 0 #26811b, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
}
```

and it is added to the end of the styles.css file as
.mytheme .v-button-sgcgreen {....}

I set the style for the button as

```
Button showAllProbesBtn = new Button("Show all");
showAllProbesBtn.addStyleName("sgcgreen");
```

But the button is default grey and does not have the specified color.

What am I missing?
Thank you for your help!

Edit:

It seems what I did is correct but just not displayed directly. Although I did Maven clean install several times and restarted the Tomcat, the correct color appeared only after I started changing something else in the code.

Where is the style cached? What do I have to do to see style changes immediately in Eclipse and in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you change the Valo variable `v-friendly-color` (see [Valo theme doc](https://vaadin.com/api/valo/#variable-v-friendly-color)). Example `mytheme.scss`:

```
// overwrite Valo variables
$v-friendly-color: #0000F0;

// Import valo after setting the parameters
@import "../valo/valo";

@mixin goidentity {
    @include valo;
}
```

The Valo theme will then take the color you set. No need to mess with CSS styles. However, I don't know if this color variable is used elsewhere in the theme. So this might effect other styles than only the friendly button.

Comment: Steffen that is  a great piece of information! I did not know that this is possible. This did work for me in Eclipse but so far not in Chrome although I restarted Chrome. Where is it cached?

Comment: I guess the browser caches the resulting `styles.css`. I do not use Chrome but found [this](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-clear-cache).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was cached in Chrome. I just found out that the images are  cached as well.